# 2 html pages with jquery effect

Tags: jquery, effect

I have two html pages.1st one is the main page with a logo and some photos and second is another page with some text.I want something like this 
http://themeforest.net/item/wave-cv-first-impression/full_screen_preview/300441
I mean when i click a logo or anywhere on first it should reveal the second page after any jquery transition.
How can i do it?

Comment: if you have the webpage that you want to mimic... you could always just view the source as JS is always open. And what's to say that data isn't AJAX'd or already populated and just hidden with a show/hide function of some kind, and a simple jQueryUI transition.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask?

Comment: i'm not really experienced with jquery.i've seen the code but it's too difficult to read.I've done with the html/css.now looking for someone to tell me about some nice tutorial so that i can learn that kind of effect from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually only one page on that example you sent, and it's not a standard jQuery effect. Initially the menu labels are hidden in the blocks you see moving when you click on the image, but I'm afraid you cannot reproduce that effect without some serious Javascript knowledge.

Although you can use firebug to watch the DOM element changing their style properties when you click on the image, then reproduce the same behaviour